# How can you switch between two jquery plugins for an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side

I have two jQuery plugins I would like to use on an image but not at the same time.  The image viewer needs to be in either a Zoom/Pan mode or a Selection mode.

I would prefer that the mode be changeable on the client side, but if there is some way to do this with ajax some how that might work too.

For this, I have the smooth Zoom plugin and the image area select plugin.
http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

This is probably way off and missing a fundamental concept about how java script and client side stuff works, but hopefully this will help explain what I am trying to do.
Below is an example of what I attempted in my ASP.NET MVC View.

**Update from comment:**"are you looking for something like a button in client side to switch between smoothZoom and imgAreaSelect?" - Yes, this is what I am looking for.

```
<script>
var flag = true;

function btnChangeModeClick() 
    {
        flag = !flag;
    }
</script>

//Code here to create a button and assign the click event to the function above

@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    //Code here to create an image element and give it a unique id that will match the scripts below

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (flag)
    {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#uniqueImageId').smoothZoom({
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#uniqueImageId').imgAreaSelect({
                handles: true
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

}

Comment: are you looking for something like a button in client side to switch between smoothZoom and imgAreaSelect?

Comment: You can keep a clone of the original image, apply two plugins on the two images. Then you can toggle their visibility using some button. There are other ways as well if you have huge amount of images in a page and this goes memory intensive.

Comment: @sabithpocker, That might work, I can probably get away with the extra memory needed on the client, but would there be a way to do that without having to create two image elements in the view that ended up asking the server for the same image twice?